# Setting a property list with Titanium Appcelerator

Tags: properties, titanium, appcelerator

I'm working with the latest Mobile SDK (1.6) on OS X.
I have this piece of code:

```
var globalArray = [
        {title:'foo',value:'yes'},
        {title:'bar',value:'no'}
]; 

Titanium.App.Properties.setList('globalArrayProperty',globalArray);
Titanium.App.Properties.getList('globalArrayProperty')[0].value = 'it works!';
Titanium.API.info('first value : ' + Titanium.App.Properties.getList('globalArrayProperty')[0].value);
```

I simplified it so that I can explain you where the problem stands.
So, I create an array with a couple of objects.
Then, I'm setting a property depending on this array and then affecting a new value to the first object. 
But when I call the display the property, instead of showing the 'it works!' string, it shows the initial one 'yes'.

I tried by adding a couple of lines:

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setList('globalArrayProperty',globalArray);
var arr = Titanium.App.Properties.getList('globalArrayProperty');
arr[0].value = 'it works!';
// This works
Titanium.API.info('first value with arr: ' + arr[0].value);
// This doesn't work
Titanium.API.info('first value : ' + Titanium.App.Properties.getList('globalArrayProperty')[0].value);
```

So the intermediate var 'arr' get the property, set it but cannot apply the modification on the property.

Am I missing something?

Thanks,

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i think you need to set the property list again after updating the array

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setList('globalArrayProperty',globalArray);
var arr = Titanium.App.Properties.getList('globalArrayProperty');
arr[0].value = 'it works!';
// This works
Titanium.API.info('first value with arr: ' + arr[0].value);

// save changes to property list
Titanium.App.Properties.setList('globalArrayProperty',arr);

// This doesn't work
Titanium.API.info('first value : ' + Titanium.App.Properties.getList('globalArrayProperty')[0].value);
```